# When I zoom my html page it scrolls up or down

Tags: html, css

Why does the page scroll when I use zoom-in or zoom-out and how can I avoid it? I tried overflow: hidden in the body but it not worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header> <h1>HEADER</h1>  </header>

        <section> <h1>SECTION</1> </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}

section{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This occurs when the elements are trying to resize, and when they do, they all squeeze together and some use line breaks which causes automatic scrolling. Web developement is not like a picture, all the elements need to be responsive for wide-screen and mobile devices.

Comment: Also in `overflow: hidden` use `!important` so you make sure the property is working. `overflow: hidden !important`

Answer (score -2):

Might! some of your status key not working properly.  Your code is not the issue Perhaps! your Ctrl key is stuck somewhere and occurring issue.